# Pythonic thread-safe object

Tags: python, multithreading, object, global

After reading a lot on this subject and discussing on IRC, the response seems to be: **stay away from threads**. Sorry for repeating this question, my intention is to go deeper in the subject by not accepting the "threading is evil" answer, with the hope to find a common solution.

EDIT: *Just Say No to the combined evils of locking, deadlocks, lock granularity, livelocks, nondeterminism and race conditions. --Guido van Rossum*

I'm developing a Python web application, and I'd like to create a **global object** for each user which is **only accessible by the current user**. (for example the requested URI)

The suggested way is to pass the object around, which IMO makes the application harder to maintain, and not beautiful code if I need the same value in different places (some might be 3rd party plugins).

I see that many popular frameworks (Django, CherryPy, Flask) use Python threading locks to solve the issue.
If all these frameworks go against the Pythonic way and feel the need to create a globally accessible object, it means that the community needs this sort of thing. And me too.

Is the "best" way to pass objects around?
Is the only alternative solution to use the "evil" threading locks?
Would it be more Pythonic to store this information in a database or memcached?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if you store the information somewhere else, you still *some* way to ensure thread-safety (e.g. avoid the common problem "thread A reads; thread B reads; A calculates new value; B calculates new value; A stores new value; B stores new value"), and that way is likely locking.

Comment: I'm curious which forums you've found that indicate that threads are to be avoided in Python.  There are reasons to choose multiprocessing over threads (when you need actual concurrency when dealing with the GIL, for example) but when your application calls for a Threaded approach, use Threads and the Locks that are provided with them.

Comment: @delnan: I agree, to ensure thread-safety the solution is threading locks, but why is it addressed as "evil" or not Pythonic?

Comment: @g.d.d.c: that's what people say on #python IRC channel, although I don't agree with thread locks being evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to lock, then either don't use globals, or use thread-local storage (in a webapp, you can be fairly sure that a request won't cross thread boundary). If global state can be avoided, it should be avoided. This makes multi-threading way easier to implement and debug.

I also disagree that passing objects around makes the application harder to maintain — it's usually the other way around — global state hides dependencies in addition to requiring careful synchronisation.

Well, there also lock-free approaches, like STM or whatnot, but it's probably an overkill for a web application.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I also prefer to avoid globals and I'll definitely check thread-local storage.

About maintainability I like reducing the amount of code as much as possible, bouncing objects sometimes limit ease of use, and I agree that dependencies have to be made very clear.

Comment: I've accepted your answer after trying out the thread-local instead of locks. It feels less hackish and more Pythonic. However, it's not yet clear why such a useful feature is labeled as bad practice.